# transient in Hibernate field from database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have hibernate `@Entity` called `Video` with fields:

```
@Column(name="TC_IN")
private BigDecimal tcIn;

@Column(name="TC_OUT")
private BigDecimal tcOut;
```

In the application, I need to convert the value to another format in order to use it.

So I added field:

```
@transient
private String formatTCOut;

public String getFormatTCOut(){
    if (formatTCOut==null){
       sysParamService = FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getBean("SysParamService");
       formatTCOut =  tcOut * sysParamService.findParamByName("accuracy");
    }
   return formatTCOut 
}
```

Is it the right to invoke another service within entity of Hibernate?\

I have `@Transactional( readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS )` above  `findParamByName` of the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion this is not a good design as it means your Hibernate object can now never be used outside of a web/JSF context.

This reduces the re-usability of the code and makes it hard to unit test.

Combining data/values from multiple beans or sources should be done at a higher level.

Comment: And if I will be using spring and not JSF bean for that - is it still fine?